# How to edit sudo permission linux file using python script

Tags: python, linux

I am appending text to a file that requires sudo permissions. When I run this python script below:

```
import subprocess
ssid= "testing"
psk= "testing1234" 
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["wpa_passphrase", ssid, psk], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["sudo","tee","-a","/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf",">","/dev/null"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
output,err = p2.communicate
```

It will append to the file as expected, but will append this:

```
network={
    ssid="testing"
    #psk="testing1234"
    psk=9891dab18debe8308a5d3bf596f5277e4a5c158bff016145830b12673ef63360
}
```

When I want this:

```
network={
    ssid="testing"
    psk="testing1234"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

This subprocess syntax is complicated to me, so I am open to an alternative method! I tried to use `f=open("appendedtext >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf")` but I need to run as `sudo` and I can't seem to find a way to do this via open(). I get a permission error.
Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: what so complicated in subprocess ? You can always get string and split it to create list `"sudo tee -a".split(" ")` or use `shell=True` and then you don't have to split it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not python or subrpocess issue, you're getting expected output from `wpa_passphrase`, see the man page:

```
NAME
       wpa_passphrase - Generate a WPA PSK from an ASCII passphrase for a SSID

SYNOPSIS
       wpa_passphrase [ ssid ] [ passphrase ]

OVERVIEW
       wpa_passphrase pre-computes PSK entries for network configuration blocks of a wpa_supplicant.conf file. An ASCII passphrase and SSID are
       used to generate a 256-bit PSK.
```

if you need plain text password just write it to file without calling `wpa_passphrase`:

```py
with open('/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf', 'a') as conf:
   conf.writelines(['network={\n', '\tssid="{0}"\n'.format(ssid), '\tpsk="{0}"\n'.format(psk), '\tkey_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n', '}\n'])
```

and don't forget to call it with `sudo`: `sudo python script.py`.